# Passing the Number of Elements in an Array to Function?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c-strings

I am writing a DLL that passes a char array to a function. I define that char array with 22 elements here:

```
unsigned char data[22] = { 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x09, 0x70, 0x00, 0x72, 0x00, 
0x6F, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x68, 0x00, 0x65, 0x00, 0x67, 0x00, 0x75, 0x00,
0x79, 0x00 };
```

Now, I try to pass this array to my function declared as:

```
bool sendData(unsigned char* sData, unsigned long sSize);
```

With these arguments:

```
sendData(data, 22);
```

This code compiles, but crashes the program when this function is called. Taking a closer look while debugging, I can see that there's an access violation in my function `sendData`. Looking even further, I see the values of `data` and `sData` at run-time:

1. `data` points to the 22 byte char array with correct values (obviously)
2. `sData` points to a char array that is null-terminated by the first byte, only containing one value (0)

It is clear to me that the compiler does not know to allocate 22 bytes for `sData`, simply because I do not specify any length for it. So my question is:

> How do I specify the length of the `sData` so that the argument
>   passed won't terminate early?

If I'm wrong about the issue, please correct me and explain it further. Thanks for any help in advance!

---

**EDIT:**

I understand that `\0` (the first byte and many more in `data`) is a null-terminator and will prematurely end the array. What I am asking is *how* to avoid this. My understanding is that `sData` is never given a specific length and therefore stops on `\0`, but I may be wrong.

I was asked to supply my sendData function:

```
bool sendData(unsigned char* sData, unsigned long sSize)
{
    try
    {
        Send(sData, sSize);
        return true;
    }
catch (...)
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

`Send` is calling a function from another module, but isn't relevant to the issue, as the error occurs beforehand when the `sData` argument is passed to `sendData`.

Comment: What happens in sendData? I would think that the debugger just tries to interpret the sData pointer as a zero terminated string.

Comment: The debugger output is just debugger treating a `char*` as a C-string. Never mind it. Your crash is unrelated and we'll need a testcase to diagnose it.

Comment: Your assumptions about NUL terminated strings (`unsigned char*`) passed as parameters are wrong. You have to show us the full code of `sendData()` to get any help here.

Comment: _"My understanding is that sData is never given a specific length and therefore stops on \0, but I may be wrong."_ Yes, you are. The only things that care about the `\0` in your array are things that decide/choose to interpret the array as a C-string, e.g. your debugger. There's no reason to think that this is your bug, unless your own code is deciding/choosing to interpret the array the same way.

Answer (score -1):

No allocation of sData is going to happen, it just points to your array. It displays as empty in the debugger because it displays a char* as a string, and strings end when there is a '/0', your first byte. This does not mean sData does not have the correct data. Write sData[0]. sData[1], etc, in your debugger to see the correct values.

Comment: Explains the debugger output, but not the crash.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit he didn't give enough info to know about the crash. By ruling this out, which he thought was the cause, he can hopefully diagnose his own crash.

Comment: True but then this is a comment not an answer. And a comment made by several other people, at that! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in fairness, I wrote this before anyone commented I think